# validation fails while checking 59 variables but works with two

Tags: php, html

hello i have created a form with 59 text box and check boxes i want to pass these boxes through a form to a page of php for validation but it fails here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['REID'], $_POST['REName'],...more variables..

{

   $REID = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9-]", "", $_POST['REID']);
   $REName = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9-]", "", $_POST['REName']); ... more variables..

   if(empty($REID) or empty($REName) ... more variables..
   {
    echo 'oop's some value missing';
   }
   else
   {
     Insertion code goes in here.
    }


}
else
{
   echo 'The variables not set';
}
```

i am using this syntax with two text boxes it works but not with 59. i am not sure weather the all variables are submitting or any other problem any one please ????????????

Comment: would you mind to post all?

Comment: Man, you're pushing the PHP to it's limits here with such a china-code... `OR`-ing 59 checks in a single `if` statement is a true hardcore, maybe you should make an array parameter and call `array_map` on it?

Comment: sorry i am a new user it just allow 570 characters not more my code is more than this amount is there any way to paste all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

That's from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/isset). So if any of those 59 variables is not set, your `if` will fail. That's expected behavior. You can try issuing a `print_r($_POST);` command to see whether those 59 variables are there. That is one of the drawbacks of using so many variables in a conditional statement that it becomes very hard to debug. You can put all those names in an array and then loop through it that will be easier than to write those 59 names over and over again in every new condition

**EDIT**

For example you could try something in these lines

```
<?php
$check=array();
$check[]="REID";
$check[]="REName";
$check[]="ThirdVar";
$check[]="FourthVar";


foreach($check as $index)
{
    if(!isset($_POST[$index]))
    {
    echo "POST does not have a value for $index <br>";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: 'If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.' then how to write my syntax sorry for stupid questions?????

Comment: $issetarray= array($_POST['REID'],
             $_POST['REName'].....more variables... Prin_r ($issetarray); this syntax is correct????

Comment: when you add `$check[]="REID"` it will add in array an index which you later want to check. So for your 59 names that you want to check just add all their names there without saying `$_POST`

Comment: beside this i want to check also for not being empty same syntax ??

Comment: its checking just the check boxes not the text boxes i check the syntax from 1 - 59 it was correct

Comment: i mean its not checking the text boxes wheter set or not its just checking the check boxes

Comment: For checkbox values your if needs to be modified slightly, goooooooogle will return a lot of results on that

Comment: the prob is with textboxes not with check boxes

Comment: Can you please update your question with the `now being used` code?